# Solve $(1-x)y''+xy'-y=-(x-1)^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

\begin{align*}
&(1-x)y''+xy'-y=-(x-1)^2&\Rightarrow\\
&(1-x)y''+y'+(x-1)y'-y=-(x-1)^2&\Rightarrow\\
&\frac{(1-x)y''+y'}{(1-x)^2}-\frac{(1-x)y'+y}{(1-x)^2}=-1&\Rightarrow\\
&\left(\frac{y'}{1-x}\right)'-\left(\frac{y}{1-x}\right)'=-1&\Rightarrow\\
&\frac{y'}{1-x}-\frac{y}{1-x}=-x+C_1&\Rightarrow\\
&y'-y=x^2-(C_1+1)x+C_1&\Rightarrow\\
&e^{-x}y'-e^{-x}y=x^2e^{-x}-(C_1+1)xe^{-x}+C_1e^{-x}&\Rightarrow\\
&(e^{-x}y)'=x^2e^{-x}-(C_1+1)xe^{-x}+C_1e^{-x}&\Rightarrow\\
&e^{-x}y=\int \left[x^2e^{-x}-(C_1+1)xe^{-x}+C_1e^{-x}\right] dx+C_2&\Rightarrow\\
&e^{-x}y=-e^{-x}(x^2-C_1x+x+1)+C_2&\Rightarrow\\
&y=-x^2+C_1x-x-1+C_2e^x.
\end{align*}

**Am I Right? Do you have better solutions?**

Comment: i got $$y(x)=C_1e^x+C_2x-x^2-1$$

Comment: "Am I right?" - Did you differentiate and check your solution? "Do you have better solutions?" - Better in what way? What is your level? Course? PS I'm not too happy about exercises like these, since even the smallest change in the problem will lead to something that cannot be solved in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: Looks like your solution is equivalent (slightly superior) to that in the OP, as you've absorbed his $-1$ into your $C_1$.

Comment: $$y(x) = -x^2 + C_1 x -x -1+C_2e^x \implies  y(x)= A e^x + B x -x^2 -1$$where $A=C_2$ and $B=C_1-1$. I think this process is good. You need not have to find any other.