# How to solve $(1-x)y'' + xy' - y = (1-x)^3$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have tried to use the solution from [Solve $(1-x)y''+xy'-y=-(x-1)^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3254547/solve-1-xyxy-y-x-12), but the idea only works when the power on the RHS is 2.

Answer (score 2):

$$(1-x)y'' + xy' - y = (1-x)^3$$
Solve the homogeneous equation
$$(1-x)y'' + xy' - y = 0$$
 by method of  reduction of order with $$y=xv(x)$$
$y=e^x$ is an obvious solution.
$$\implies y_h(x)=c_1e^x+c_2x$$
Use the method of variation of constants for the particular solution

---

**Another approach**

Substitute $u=x-1$ The equation becomes:
$$uy'' -(u+1)y' +y = u^3$$
$$uy''-y' -(uy' -y) = u^3$$
$$\frac {uy''-y'}{u^2} -\frac {(uy' -y)}{u^2} = u$$
$$(\frac {y'}{u})' -(\frac y{u})' = u$$
Integrate:
$$\frac {y'}{u} -\frac y{u} = \frac {u^2}2+c_1$$
$$y' - y = \frac {u^3}2+c_1u$$
$$(ye^{-u})' =e^{-u} \left ( \frac {u^3}2+c_1u \right )$$
Integrate again:
$$\boxed {y(x)=e^{u} \int e^{-u} \left ( \frac {u^3}2+c_1u \right )du}$$
You just need to evaluate the last integral

Answer (score 1):

$$(x-1)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-x\frac{dy}{dx}+y=(x-1)^3 \tag 1$$
Change of variable : $x=t+1$
$$t\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}-(t+1)\frac{dy}{dt}+y=t^3 \tag 2$$
Search for a particular solution on the form $y_p=At^3+Bt^2+Ct+D$

$t(6At+2B)-(t-1)(3At^2+2Bt+C)+(At^3+Bt^2+Ct+D)=t^3$

After simplification : $-(2A+1)t^3+(3A-B)t^2+B-C=0$

which implies $A=-\frac12\quad;\quad B=-\frac32\quad;\quad B=C$

For example a particular solution is 
$$y_p(t)=-\frac12t^3-\frac32t^2$$
Change of function : 
$$y(t)=Y(t)+y_p=Y(t)-\frac12t^3-\frac32t^2$$
Puting it into Eq.$(2)$ leads to :
$$t\frac{d^2Y}{dt^2}-(t+1)\frac{dY}{dt}+Y=0 \tag 3$$
This is a linear homogeneous ODE easy to solve : $\quad t(Y'-Y)'-(Y'-Y)=0$

$\frac{(Y-Y')'}{(Y-Y')}=\frac{1}{t}\quad$ Integration gives : $Y'-Y=c_1t$
$$Y=c_1(t+1)+c_2e^t$$
$$y(t)=c_1(t+1)+c_2e^t-\frac12t^3-\frac32t^2$$
$$y(x)=c_1x+c_2e^{x-1}-\frac12(x-1)^3-\frac32(x-1)^2$$
After rearranging the arbirary constants $C_1=c_1+\frac32$ and $C_2=e^{-1}c_2$ :
$$\boxed{y(x)=C_1x+C_2e^x-\frac12x^3-1}$$